# How to set Php's auto_prepend_file directive per directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2

Background: I've got some code that checks to see if a user has a valid session before processing the php page that I would like to set as the auto_prepend_file.  However, I need to exclude the page where the user attempts to login from requiring a valid session.  I would like to be able to set the auto_prepend_file value on an per directory basis.

Environment: PHP 5.2.6m Apache 2, running php as a cgi not as mod_php, on Windows (if that matters) and on a machine that I have complete control over (not a hosted environment)

Using a htaccess file is out b/c I am not using mod_php.  I have not been able to alter the  in php.ini to set the auto_prepend_file, the server throws an internal error.  And ini_set() does not work b/c it has already loaded the session checking file before I can change the value of auto_prepend_file.

I do not see a way to set auto_prepend_file on a per directory basis if you are not using mod_php/htaccess.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What web server software do you use?

Comment: @Gumbo good point...just updated to say Apache 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .user.ini files.

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: It's worth the upgrade if you have control over that. Otherwise, you'll need to edit the main Apache configuration files.

Comment: This is just a link answer thus it should be downvoted or removed completely, It doesn't matter if it helps the person who asked the question, because some highly knowledgeable, disciplined and a reputation hogger told me in comment so. I mean come on, you should provide the code snippet, may be the code of whole file, or may be you should complete whole project, or you should earn money for him for whole life for the person who asked the question. Yes that's should be done.

Answer (score 9):

You mention you can't use .htaccess files but can you make modifications to httpd.conf and do something like this:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/dev/">
    Php_value auto_prepend_file c:/wamp/www/dev/prepend.php
</Directory>
```

**EDIT** - just realised this doesnt work when running as CGI. I think though that one thing that will work is if you create a copy of your php.ini file, place it in the directory,  and put your prepend directive in there like:

```
auto_prepend_file = c:/wamp/www/dev/prepend.php
```

Comment: That did not work for me on my system...should it be working?

Comment: What could be preventing this from working on my machine?  When I put that line it I get this error message when restarting apache: Invalid command 'Php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Thank you for updating your response.

Answer (score -2):

There is a great tutorial called: [Automatically Include Files with PHP & Apache](http://www.aarongloege.com/blog/web-development/php/automatically-include-files/) that explain how to do that with the **apache directive** and **PHP** code to append at the end. First, define a file to catch the page before it's outputted and append whatever you want:

```
<?php
{
  $script = <<<GA
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-y']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
GA;
  $replace = array('</body>','</BODY>');
  $page = str_replace($replace, "{$script}\r</body>", $page);
//   $replace2 = array('</title>','</TITLE>');
//   $page = str_replace($replace2, " - My Awesome Site</title>", $page);
  return $page;
}
ob_start("appendToFile");
?>
```

Then add the Apache directive to your virtual host. You need to **prepend** the PHP file in order to use the `ob_start()` method :

```
<Directory "/path/to/folder">
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
    php_value auto_prepend_file /absolute/path/to/apache-prepend.php
</Directory>
```