# How to config apache virtual host to let every php script include one or more common php script?

Tags: php, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set Php's auto_prepend_file directive per directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248140/how-to-set-phps-auto-prepend-file-directive-per-directory)

for the whole php site, I want to let every php script include a common php file.

How can i config apache virtual host to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your server config you should be able to use [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) in your **.htaccess** file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "config.php"
```

Or, for **Virtual Host**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    php_value auto_prepend_file "config.php"
</VirtualHost>
```