# How do I resolve "PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required"

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have two sites on a LAMP stack. One (Site1) uses WordPress with Wordfence, and it works perfectly fine. The second website (Site2) only runs a simple index.php file on it:

```
<?php
echo "Testing";
?>
```

However, it shows HTTP ERROR 500 with the error log as below.

```
[Thu Dec 22 16:23:44.774993 2016] [:error] [pid 56607] [client xxx:27253] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Dec 22 16:23:44.775042 2016] [:error] [pid 56607] [client xxx:27253] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/site1/public_html/public/wordfence-waf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Site1 and Site2 have nothing to do with each other, and they are located in separate folders. I am not sure what's happening. Please advise.

*.htaccess* file on Site1

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
        php_value auto_prepend_file '/var/www/site1/public_html/public/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

Comment: The system is using that .htaccess for both sites. Is the second site a subdomain of the first (or is its root folder somewhere inside the root folder for the first site)?

Comment: Hi @EdCottrell. They are separate site. The structure is:

Comment: /var/www/html/site1 and /var/www/html/site2

Comment: Maybe php's auto prepend feature is set?

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248140/how-to-set-phps-auto-prepend-file-directive-per-directory) might have your answer.

Comment: Thanks @EdCottrell for great help! I put the auto_prepend_file to the apache configuration file and the sites works now. (yay)

Comment: Thanks @arkascha too :)

Comment: @DaleNguyen glad to help! I'd write it up as an answer, but I'm not 100% sure where you put it. Feel free to post an answer yourself if you'd like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @EdCottrell. I finally found an answer for that.

First, I debug to find where the ***php.ini*** locates by create a info.php on the working site.

```
<? php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then, I find if there is any value on *auto_prepend_file =*. If yes, delete it.

Then I open the ***site1.conf*** file and add the *auto_prepend_file* line instead of the one from .htaccess

```
<Directory "/path/to/folder">
    php_value auto_prepend_file /absolute/path/to/apache-prepend.php
</Directory>
```

After restarting the Apache server, everything works again!

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried to run

```
docker run --t -v .:/project php
```

when I tried to do

```
/project:$ php file.php
```

I got this error.

Apparently, you can't use bound volumes from docker that easily. So I copied the volume inside the container, and used a copy.

```
docker run --t -v .:/project php
```

```
/project:$ cd ..
/:$ cp -r /project /project2
/:$ cd /project2
/project2: $ php file.php
```

and it worked.