# Include one file to all files

Tags: php, include

I did create a php file named parentfile.php and in a directory /phpdirectory/ i created many php files named php1.php php2.php php3.php ....
is it possible to include parentfile.php to all php files in phpdirectory ? without using include in every php file I create.
the parentfile.php will automatically include to any file I will create inside /phpdirectory/.

similar to mvc you create a class extract controller will use controller without using include or extract to module will user module without using include

Comment: In a simple manner - no, there's no way.

Comment: Maybe using php.ini `auto_prepend_file` ? Here's how to set it per directory in apache2 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248140/how-to-set-phps-auto-prepend-file-directive-per-directory